# How to create a bean remotely without changing the actual class in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot

My requirement is to `@Autowire` a regular *Java class* without changing it. The solutions that I saw are by annotiating that class with `@Component` or `@Service` but I can not change the actual class. Is there another way that I can do it? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a bean with:

- an xml configuration file
- a [java config file](https://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.m3/reference/html/creating-bean-definitions.html)
- annotation (`@Component`, `@Service`, `@Controller`, `@Repository`...) on the bean class

So you can easily use the first two methods.
For example you can use a class annotated with `@Configuration`:

> Annotating a class with the **@Configuration** annotation indicates that the class will be used by JavaConfig as a **source of bean definitions**.

Here is the code

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {

   @Bean
   public MyBean getMyBean() {
     MyBean myBean = ...

     return myBean;
   }
}

...

@Component
public class AnotherClass {

  @Autowired
  private MyBean myBean;

  ...
 }
```

---

Updated answer with informations related to the comment of the questionnaire:

If you can't use a constructor you can get an istance of the class using:

```
   @Bean
   public MyBean getMyBean() {
     MyBean myBean = MyBean.getInstance();

     return myBean;
   }
```

or you can use it directly in your class without using the `@Autowired` annotation because is not spring that instantiates `MyBean` instance for you, but the `getInstance` method. The code will become:

```
@Component
public class AnotherClass {

                       // Creates (or get) the instance 
  private MyBean myBean = MyBean.getInstance();

  ...
 }
```

NOTE: If you are a fan of the TDD the first solution generates a code that is much simpler to test than the second because there is no direct reference to a static `getInstance` method so it is easier to generate a mock.

Comment: I can't create a new object with that class. It says the constructor of SampleClass is not visible. The only thing that I can do is SampleClass.getInstance(). This SampleClass is actually inside a jar file. Do you know the solution for that?

Comment: I can't edit that file because it is inside a jar file. With getInstance() method it doesn't work as well.

Comment: Thanks for your help.